# Как изменить никнейм на stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, настройки-профиля

Подскажите, как можно изменить никнейм на "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: _никнейм_ - это отображаемое имя?

Comment: Hello. Да отображаемое имя.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Для изменения отображаемого имени нужно:

1. Зайти в свой профиль
2. Перейти на вкладку "Править"
3. Выбрать пункт "Редактировать Профиль"
4. Изменить значение поля "Отображаемое Имя"
5. Сохранить изменения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]