# Как узнать старый ник участника, если он его сменил?

Tags: поддержка

Навеяно [комментарием](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5874/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-enso#comment22466_5874) @NickVolynkin:

> @Skyrocker не узнаю вас в гриме.

На сайте есть [возможность менять имя пользователя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4243/176217) и иногда после таких переименований (и дополнительной смены аватарки) участника бывает трудно узнать.

Можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы получить старый ник участника?

Comment: Разрушаете и без того жалкие возможности анонимизации. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin учётку модератора в каждый дом!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В большинстве контекстов, где отображается ник участника, после переименования будет отображаться уже новый ник (вопросы, ответы, голоса в очередях проверок и т.д.). Но как минимум в одном случае ник остается таким, каким он был на момент выполнения действия. И это действие называется - ответ по нику в комментарии.

В этом случае ник сохраняется в базе как текст, и если участнику, сменившему ник, кто-то отвечал в комментариях (это с большой вероятностью должны быть комментарии к чужим сообщениям), то оттуда можно узнать и прежний ник.

А найти старые комментарии не так и сложно, они доступны к просмотру для любого. Достаточно зайти в профиль участника, который сменил ник и выбрать там: все действия - комментарии - переместиться на самые старые. Открыть ссылку и увидеть как обращались к участнику в то время.

Comment: Забываете ещё важную вещь - если участник в чате бывает, сообщения хранятся от имени того, кто был на момент их создания. Можно увидеть [сообщения от кого-то, с ником @Other](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=37508756#37508756). ID будет одним. Однако аватарка будет новой о_0

Comment: @Skyrocker поэтому у меня и указано "как минимум". Могли бы расписать свой подход отдельным ответом. Но Вам, наверное, лень :)

Comment: Несмотря на новый ник, Вы узнали меня и знаете мои особенности :) Можете добавить описание к себе в ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Одна из возможных альтернатив - составить запрос к WayBack Machine. Например, замените в нижеследующей ссылке циферки на ID пользователя.

```
https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/*
```

Comment: Такие снапшоты всё же реже создаются, нежели участник получает ответы в комментариях. Вот в данном конкретном случае, ник только один поймался, хотя их было больше.

Answer (score 3):

Можно типо [такого запроса](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22users/15479/%22%20site:ru.stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=925) к гуглу использовать. Но там будут только ссылки на проиндексированные страницы.

Ещё есть [такая штука](http://msleziak.com/stackexchange/oldusernames/), которая с помощью API получает список комментариев пользователя (а там оригинальный ник отображается).

К примеру, если подставить ссылку на профиль @alexolut https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217, то:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое ощущение, что просто собрали все очепятки :)

Comment: @alexolut лучше, чем ничего)

Comment: С удалёнными пользователями не работает.

Comment: @alexolut у удалённых же ник в комментариях заменяется на userXXX, не?

Comment: [любопытненько...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlKcv.jpg)

Comment: @alexolut только никому не говорите, что Николас мой твинк.

Comment: Оно еще почему-то на Enter у меня всё обнуляет (надо именно кнопку формы жать), или это проблемы iOS.

Comment: Ну, может это какой-то другой КМ... :-D

Comment: @alexolut у меня тут их целый вагон.